# List a directory with SSH inside SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, ls

I need to list the contents of a directory that is on another server in a single line of code. For that, I need to connect to a server and, from this server, I need to go to the final server, via SSH.

Today I have the following script that works perfectly and generates the output below:

```
ssh user@server1 'ls -ltr /oracle/archive/server/*.arc --time-style=+"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S" | awk '"'"'{gsub("/u01/archive/servidor/servidor_1_","");gsub("_123456789.arc","");print $8" - "$6" "$7}'"'" ' | sort -n | tail -5'

1921077 - 11/07/2022 17:28:34
1921078 - 11/07/2022 17:28:45
1921079 - 11/07/2022 17:28:50
1921080 - 11/07/2022 17:31:22
1921081 - 11/07/2022 17:35:17
```

When making the intended change, I get the errors below, pointing out the files that exist on server1 and do not exist on server2:

```
ssh user@server1 ssh user@server2 'ls -ltr /oracle/archive/server/*.arc --time-style=+\"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S\" | awk '"'"'{gsub("/u01/archive/servidor/servidor_1_","");gsub("_123456789.arc","");print $8" - "$6" "$7}'"'" ' | sort -n | tail -5'

ls: cannot access /u01/archive/servidor/servidor_1_1921082_123456789.arc: No such file or directory
1921077 - 11/07/2022 17:28:34
1921078 - 11/07/2022 17:28:45
1921079 - 11/07/2022 17:28:50
1921080 - 11/07/2022 17:31:22
1921081 - 11/07/2022 17:35:17
```

Comment: Quoting problems?

Comment: If you need to go through one server to get to another, it's best to configure a `ProxyHost` in your `.ssh/config`. That will handle passing through transparently, and you won't have quoting problems.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.